# Kubuntu Plasma Wallpaper reverts to default on bootup

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, desktop-background

After a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04 (due to having to reformat the OS drive) my chosen wallpaper, not part of the distribution, reverts to the default that is part of the distro. When I was running 14.04, I somehow got it to retain my chosen wallpaper, which I change seasonally. Unfortunately, I have forgotten how I did that, and now have to re-establish the desktop each time I have to reboot. Kind of a headache. I've reviewed a number of Kubuntu forums & search engines, but have only found how to change the default wallpaper, through a somewhat inconvenient method, that is untenable. Is there a solution to cause KDE to retain whichever wallpaper I set via Configure Desktop regardless of rebooting?

I may not have given enough detail here, so if you need further info, please ask for it and mention how the needed info is found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this provides a clue, I should have mentioned that the wallpaper selections in the Configure Desktop panel also revert to the default (factory) wallpapers on a random basis, not consistently.

Comment: **1:** When you say "on a random basis", do you mean that the wallpaper doesn't revert after reboot each time you reboot or only sometimes? **2:** where do you store your custom wallpapers?

Comment: I should have been more clear. The Configure Desktop Panel which shows the "factory" wallpapers along with those I've selected from files sometimes show the ones I've selected, but are not clickable, other times are gone altogether, leaving only the "factory" ones built into the distro. At these times, I have to navigate to the directory where the files are, and select them again. This seems to be an instability, since it's not consistent. Hope this clears it up, and I appreciate your reply.

Comment: I don't use wallpapers myself, but I downloaded one from the KDE store (via the GUI in `Configure Desktop`) and it was stored in `~/.local/share/wallpapers/`. Maybe you can try keeping your wallpapers there?

Comment: I don't have a \wallpapers\ folder in 18.04. Perhaps one was created for you when you downloaded from KDE. I assume (a dangerous thing) that I may be able to simply create such a folder and move my picture files into it? Yes, I'm a bit paranoid about doing something the system will have a disagreement with. Would this also correct the reboot problem? Again, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Creating `~/.local/share/wallpapers/` and moving *your* wallpapers there is unlikely to blow things up. As for whether it will fix your problems, I can't really say. That folder was created when I downloaded a wallpaper as I explained earlier.

Comment: The problem of Kubuntu wallpaper not retaining my selected file is still a problem. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Consider asking at https://www.kubuntuforums.net and at https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/