# Cannot log into Kubutu 18.04 after removing widgets that didn't work correctly, using Discover

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, widgets

After consulting a web site stating that undesirable widgets could be removed using Discover, the process removed several items that are now preventing me from logging in. Before, I had Kubuntu set to just log me in, without a login screen. Now, I get a mostly blue screen with an analog clock, my identity name and password box. The password box does not respond at all when my password is entered. Below this is a message stating it could not find: 
file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/main.qml

After searching the hard drive, using Dolphin running from a live CD, I found numerous iterations of the main.qml file (about 20) with various dates. I moved the most recent iteration to the directory noted above, but no change in status. In my web search, I found a a couple of possible solutions, including:
1. rm .kde/share/config/kdeglobals, then log out (cannot log in to perform this)
2. Ctrl Alt+7 then log in (doesn't work)
   run rm -rf .kde/share/config/plasma-*, then Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Alt+F2
   Ctrl+Alt+F7 or Ctrl+Alt+F1 (can't get to this without being able to log in.

I'm trying to restore functionality without wiping the hard drive and starting over, as this will be very time consuming.

My questions are:

1. Why is Discover written to remove packages & files that are still needed, instead of just removing the offending application or widget?
2. Is there a solution to reinstall SDDM or Plasma?
3. How can I remove Widgets that do not work as intended, without removing needed packages/files?
4. How can I find which version of Plasma I'm using?

Please bear in mind that I'm not a software engineer, so cannot understand many complex solutions. I will be glad to supply any other needed information, but will need to be directed where to find such information.

Comment: **1**: I avoid Discover. Use Synaptic Package Manager or the command-line. **2**: If you can't login, doing a clean install may end up being quicker. I don't prefer the autologin option. **3**: To remove widgets in your panel, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1153566. For a widget on the desktop, left-click on the widget (and hold) until you see a small panel appear with a red "close" icon (like the one in the answer I linked). Clicking on that will remove the widget. **4**: When you have access to a terminal, `plasmashell --version` tells you the version. The GUI way is to open KInfoCenter.

Comment: I also wonder if part of your problems as in https://askubuntu.com/q/1094638 is the use of `sudo` when not necessary. Doing so would cause certain files to be owned by *root*.

Comment: Isn't there any sort of repair utility or procedure built-in to Ubuntu?